# Cant get values from different radio buttons groups

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I want to know what am I missing. I have this radio inputs in a form:

```
<input type="radio" name="consulta" value="Ingreso">Ingreso
<input type="radio" name="consulta" value="Inversion">Inversi&oacute;n y Crecimiento<br<br>
<label style="font-weight:500;">Tipo:</label>
<input type="radio" name="tipo" value="Mensual">Mensual
<input type="radio" name="tipo" value="Diaria">Diaria
```

and to retrieve the selected value from each group i have this javascript code inside a function:

```
var tipoConsulta = $('input[@name="consulta"]:checked').val();
var frecuenciaConsulta = $('input[@name="tipo"]:checked').val();
```

The problem is that the "frecuenciaConsulta" variable takes the same value that the "tipoConsulta" variable, both variables get the selected value from the first group. I dont know what im doing wrong, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square brackets are already an attribute select, no need for the @ symbol, try

```
var tipoConsulta = $('input[name="consulta"]:checked').val();
var frecuenciaConsulta = $('input[name="tipo"]:checked').val();
```

**EDIT**

Just out of interest, the syntax including the @ symbol for an attribute was valid up to jQuery 1.3

reference link

[jQuery Attribute Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `@`:

```
var tipoConsulta = $('input[name="consulta"]:checked').val();
var frecuenciaConsulta = $('input[name="tipo"]:checked').val();
```